# Very slow Octave execution: 52x10^4 simple loop taking forever

Tags: performance, octave, execution-time

I haven't programmed in a long time and have no references for reasonable execution times. Here is the code I'm running (I did not find a way to vectorize it). It's taking a very long time on a i5-4570T@2.90GHz with plenty of RAM. Any comments on why it's taking a long time/how I can speed it up are welcomed. I'm basically add one random element at a time and recalculate maximum run length.

```
N = 52 % Number of cards
Iter = 10000 

s=zeros(Iter,N);
MAX=zeros(Iter,N);

for ii=1:Iter

  A=randperm(N); % shuffle the deck
  L=zeros(1,N);
  for jj=1:N
      L(A(jj))=1;
      [count,value]=runlength(L);
      runs = count(find(value==1));
      s(ii,jj)=max(runs);
      MAX(ii,jj)=length(find(runs==s(ii,jj)));
    end
end
```

Comment: Check out `profile`, it's designed to tell you what's slow. Also, you're missing a semicolon after `max(runs)` and `zeros(1,N)`.

Comment: Using [logical indexing](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Logical-Values.html), `count(find(value==1))` could be replaced with `count(value==1)`. Similarly, `length(find(runs==s(ii,jj)))` could be replaced with `nnz(runs==s(ii,jj))` or `sum(runs==s(ii,jj))`.